# mvvm-light : losing intellisense on VS2012

Tags: intellisense, mvvm-light

We are using MVVM Light Toolkit (from Galasoft - Laurent Bugnion).
Until now we were using Visual Studio 2010.
Everything was working well (thanks to Laurent).

Two days ago we moved to Visual Studio 2012.
And now Intellisense is no longer working in Xaml files (but still working in code-behind).

After looking on forums and made some tests, it appears that we have an issue with "GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL5.dll".

As soon as GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL5.dll is removed from project references, intellisense is working again.

Someone already had same problem and/or know a solution ?

Thanks.

Alain.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem when we migrated from Silverlight 4 to 5. We were using a local copy of GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL5.dll copied from another computer.

Once we installed the MvvmLight .msi package and changed the reference in our Silverlight project to C:\Program Files (x86)\[...]\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL5.dll, IntelliSense started working again.

Hope this helps